# Can I limit Google OAuth 2.0’s login to specific Google accounts only?

Tags: jenkins, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

So far I know how to limit the login to within my own organization but what if I want to further limit to only specific users, like a specific team?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention, this is for my new Jenkins setup and I setup my Jenkins on a Mac.

Comment: What you only want some people to be able to authenticate?

Comment: @DaImTo yes, so that I'll have tight control on who can access and work on my Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is :

1. Create resource server on Google with scopes like:
   .Admin
   .Staff
   and so on
2. When you contact /tokeninfo endpoint, you will get the username, then check with LDAP regarding user's role, if role >= roles as part of scopes then grant access otherwise deny the access.

Comment: Could you guide me how to implement the 2 suggestions? If elaboration is too much of a hassle then any web tutorial or web guide would still be great!

Comment: I guess even adding custom attribute to Google are not needed. You can simply allow the regular flow to happen then if your application is deployed int any J2EE container then simply create a container level filter to do contact Google OAuth to get User token details and then talk to your LDAP to get the user role information, check if role is sufficient to execute given scopes from token

Comment: When I say given scopes from this token, I mean check if scopes from token pertains to current URL and operation being requested. If that is OK then allow access otherwise return unauthorized access.

Comment: Regarding your question of tutorial, I could not find any but I will try looking today and if found anything will update here

Comment: I found out that in Jenkins, there's an access control to limit which email accounts are allowed to login. Since this is not related to OAuth so I'll leave this question open, in case in future Google does implement such restriction option for OAuth, then hopefully a samaritan can answer for me.

Comment: Great, Even I spent good deal of time to figure that out but could not find anything, No reason Custom OAuth providers are providing lot of Enterprise required functionality...